How should I keep armature handles close to the actual mesh when posing the armature?
Using Blender 4.1
I'm currently learning how to rig and want to learn how to use bone constraints properly. Here is my WIP rig thus far:

When I move the root bone (the first spine bone, by the pelvis bones) it moves the entire armature as it should, and the limb IK bones point in the direction towards the IK handles (the red circles).

However, I want the IK handles to be constrained by distance so that it sticks near the parts it is meant to control (so the IK handles near the hands will always stay near the hands until the mesh cannot stretch any further).
After the above example, I added the 'Limit Distance' constraint to the handle bones but this provided very unstable results (the rig would not go back to its original position after right-clicking to cancel a transformation, when distance is set to 0 it won't allow me to move the handles, when I want to reset the rig to rest position I had to repeat that operation several times as the limit distance constraint kept applying, etc.)

Here are the settings for the deformation bones controlled by the handle, in case that helps.

I feel like I'm running into an order or operations problem, as I'm sure the Limit Distance bone constraint is what I need but I can't seem to get it to work right. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to properly create rig handles that help with IK efficiency?
Thanks!

Hello, I'm not sure to understand your setup, maybe share your file, generally there's a root bone that is a big bone under the feet, parent the spine bone and all the IK target and pole target bones to it.
